# FFMPEG Merge Multiple Videos: No Audio Source for one of them

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I've written a node.js script to merge multiple video files into a single file. I've encountered a scenario in which no audio is provided for one of the input video files.

I first executed **ffprobe** so that I can access what I'll refer to as the "video file spec". In this scenario, I created a basic module to help me better understand my problem:

```
Evaluation from all processes: [
  {
    fileName: 'input-0.mp4',
    isVideoAvailable: true,
    isAudioAvailable: false,
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    sampleRateAspectRatio: '1/1',
    audioVolume: 1,
    duration: '13.140000'
  },
  {
    fileName: 'input-1.mp4',
    isVideoAvailable: true,
    isAudioAvailable: true,
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    sampleRateAspectRatio: '1/1',
    audioVolume: 1,
    duration: '17.160000'
  },
  {
    fileName: 'input-2.mp4',
    isVideoAvailable: true,
    isAudioAvailable: true,
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    sampleRateAspectRatio: '1/1',
    audioVolume: 1,
    duration: '20.280000'
  },
  {
    fileName: 'input-3.mp4',
    isVideoAvailable: true,
    isAudioAvailable: true,
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    sampleRateAspectRatio: '1/1',
    audioVolume: 1,
    duration: '19.020000'
  },
  {
    fileName: 'input-4.mp4',
    isVideoAvailable: true,
    isAudioAvailable: true,
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    sampleRateAspectRatio: '1/1',
    audioVolume: 1,
    duration: '9.480000'
  }
]
```

This next block of code are the parameters that I've actually hard-coded in this case. The screen resolution and aspect ratio are manually set, as I discovered differing settings with each video I have been processing. These parameters allow FFMPEG to execute successfully under normal circumstances:

```
let ffmpegParameters = [
  '-i',
  'input-0.mp4',
  '-i',
  'input-1.mp4',
  '-i',
  'input-2.mp4',
  '-i',
  'input-3.mp4',
  '-i',
  'input-4.mp4',
  '-f',
  'lavfi',
  '-t',
  '0.1',
  '-i',
  'anullsrc',
  '-filter_complex',
  '[0:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v0];[0:a]volume=1.0[a0];[1:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v1];[1:a]volume=1.0[a1];[2:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v2];[2:a]volume=1.0[a2];[3:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v3];[3:a]volume=1.0[a3];[4:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v4];[4:a]volume=1.0[a4];[v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3][v4][a4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[v][a]',
  '-map',
  '[v]',
  '-map',
  '[a]',
  '-c:v',
  'libx264',
  '-vsync',
  '2',
  'output.mp4'
]
```

A comment from a different thread suggested to supply a dummy audio in cases such as mine. I've added that to no prevail:

```
  '-f',
  'lavfi',
  '-t',
  '0.1',
  '-i',
  'anullsrc',
```

I do not know how to adjust the complex filter to account for my situation of the first video containing no audio. I've included the entire log below:

```
Logs:
 ffmpeg version git-2020-02-03-1c15111
 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-appkit --enable-avfoundation --enable-coreimage --enable-audiotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 67.100 / 58. 67.100
  libavformat    58. 37.100 / 58. 37.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 73.100 /  7. 73.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input-0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.37.100

  Duration: 00:00:14.80, start: 1.620000, bitrate: 1499 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1498 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 2400k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler

Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input-1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.37.100
  Duration: 00:00:18.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 977 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1440x876 [SAR 1:1 DAR 120:73], 903 kb/s, 15.21 fps, 16.67 tbr, 16k tbn, 32k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input-2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.37.100
  Duration: 00:00:22.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1795 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1718 kb/s, 29.54 fps, 50 tbr, 16k tbn, 32k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler

Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input-3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.37.100
  Duration: 00:00:54.60, start: 
0.000000, bitrate: 404 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1440x876 [SAR 1:1 DAR 120:73], 330 kb/s, 15.24 fps, 16.67 tbr, 16k tbn, 32k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #3:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler

Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input-4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.37.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.36
, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1794 kb/s
    Stream #4:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1717 kb/s, 29.38 fps, 50 tbr, 16k tbn, 32k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #4:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler

Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v0];[0:a]volume=1.0[a0];[1:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v1];[1:a]volume=1.0[a1];[2:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v2];[2:a]volume=1.0[a2];[3:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v3];[3:a]volume=1.0[a3];[4:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v4];[4:a]volume=1.0[a4];[v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3][v4][a4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[v][a] matches no streams.
```

When I removed the stream specifier **[a0]**, I received a different error:

```
FFmpeg Video Merge - STDERR: [Parsed_setsar_3 @ 0x7f87c7709100] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_setsar_3' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_concat_14' filter input pad 1 (audio)
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f87c7430c00] Cannot create the link setsar:0 -> concat:1
```

My question is how will the filter-complex value of my parameter list that I have defined be adjusted to deal with that first video, which has no audio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description … matches no streams`

You are referencing a stream that does not exist. In this case it is due to `[0:a]volume=1.0[a0]`. You are attempting to select audio from `input-0.mp4`, but this input has no audio.

#### `Media type mismatch`

I don't know your exact command so I can't point out the actual cause, but your video and audio filter labels are likely mixed up somewhere.

---

## Working Example

```
ffmpeg -i input-0.mp4 -i input-1.mp4 -i input-2.mp4 -i input-3.mp4 -i input-4.mp4 -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=44100 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1/1[v0];[1:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v1];[2:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v2];[3:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v3];[4:v]scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v4];[v0][5][v1][1:a][v2][2:a][v3][3:a][v4][4:a]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- Since `volume=1` does absolutely nothing you can eliminate that filter.
- For the video input without audio pair it with the anullsrc output in concat (as with `[v0][5]` in the example above).
- [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) will automatically select a common sample rate and channel layout for audio streams, but I still prefer to manually set them in anullsrc so I know for sure what I'm going to get.
- Your inputs vary in DAR, so the 1440x876 videos will look squished in the output. You can avoid this by adding [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) + [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) or [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad). Since they all have the same SAR refer to [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit into static size](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/).
- Upscaling is usually not a great idea. Consider downscaling to 1280x720 instead since half the inputs are that size.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response! I have learned a lot in that working example that you have provided. And thank you for the notice that it is better for me to scale as opposed to scaling up.You are truly amazing!

So in that example, I only needed to specify the video. Is it safe to say the "[5]" corresponds to the fifth input, which is that null audio source? It looks like for each video I determine contains no audio, I will specify that "null audio stream specifier". 

I was forced to add "-vsync 2" to your working exampe--those video frames were clashing.

THANK YOU! THANK YOU!

Comment: @CoachRoebuck `[5]` actually refers to the sixth input (anullsrc as you said) because it starts counting from 0. For each video that has no audio it needs a corresponding audio to pair it with: being silent audio from anullsrc, or any other audio file or source.